# iOS simulator show different colour with same UIColor

Tags: ios

Here is the problem. I use UIColor to some views and I used colour meter to compare colour in simulator with colour in an image, they are the same. This simulator is running on iMac.

Now I have another macbook air running same code, but the colour is different from that original image. And I can see it is different from the simulator on iMac.

EDIT:

DigitalColor Meter gave me the same value for both simulator, but the value for original image is different.

Comment: Are you saying the color is different between a device and the simulator?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wrong color in Interface Builder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578759/wrong-color-in-interface-builder)

Comment: Probably an issue with the graphics between iMac and Macbook Air, not with the actual code in the application. Different computers display colors differently, and this seems like the case because you are using the simulator. The problem will probably go away when you begin testing on an actual device.

Comment: @ThomasW I have two macs. When I'm running simulator on them, colour is different.

Comment: @BrianTracy Yeah, I agree with that. So which colour should I use in order to have same look and feel as the image if i'm running on device? That make the implementation and design as close as possible?

Comment: @SnowWolf Don't change the color. It has nothing to do with the color, its the probably the way your two different computers are displaying the color. I recommend testing on an actual device to see which color is right for you, because that is the color that will be shown on other devices.

Comment: And even then it will differ from device to device. In fact, in iOS 7.1 the user can change color saturation in Settings! So let's face it, you are not in 100% control of what color the user will see.