# Match color between UIView and CALayer(CGColor)

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer, background-color, color-space

I have an UIView (inside a LaunchScreen, so not many options customizing it), for which I've specified a backgroundColor through IB. The first VC that comes up after the app launches has a CALayer that should be identical to the LaunchScreen... except it isn't.

I know there is some color correction applied, but I can't seem to find the relevant documentation to understand the process. I would assume I need to specify the correct color space when creating the CGColor that's used as a background for the CALayer.

Comment: You are applying color to the LaunchScreen using Interface Builder, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can set color for CALayer

```
layer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor greenColor] CGColor]; //obj c
layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor.cgColor //swift
```

It will set the same `greenColor` you applied to launch screen.

If your setting RGB value in interface, take care for selecting right RGB profile,

[image]

Comment: That’s what I did... turns out it’s not the same.

Comment: check your launch screen interface, may you have applied alpha

Comment: Alpha is 1 everywhere, that’s not an issue

Comment: Apply colors to LaunchScreen using Generic RGB profile [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33557303/1556386)