# Taking color code from indesign in RGB code and use iOS app look different color

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, interface-builder, uicolor

In InDesign

[image]

In Photoshop jpeg exported from InDesign

[image]

this is how it looks on the real device

[image]

I saw the strange issue that when I take color code in RGB format or hexacode from Adobe InDesign file for a UI element like button and set that in my Xcode from interface builder to the button, it looks different color on App on iPhone(6) real device and simulator(All device simulator) both.

but when I export the InDesign file to jpeg and open in photoshop and take the color code from there
then

1. It shows different color code from InDesign file (Strange).
2. If I use that color code in Xcode in interface builder then it shows again different color in real device and simulator. But when I take a snapshot of the simulator and compare in photoshop that simulator snapshot image with jpeg( I exported from InDesign), they show same color code but looks different color on iPhone real device.

I want the color code that works for me and looks same as InDesign have.

How can I get that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wrong color in Interface Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578759/wrong-color-in-interface-builder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Followed these steps to resolve my problem

- Add the color in Assets.xcassets folder in your Project. click on + button
  and select New Color Set[image]
- set color in sRGB color space as [image]
- I use hex code that is given in InDegisn and it works.
- Use it in storyboard as [image]
- in code as [image]

**Note** - this will work on ios 11 and above.