# Add a custom color palette to Xcode Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

My current long term project utilizes a palette of custom colors. In code, we are using a category to access these colors by name. This works great but there are times, such as when building a nib, that these colors won't be set programmatically.

I am looking for a way to define a named set of colors. For instance, when setting a background color for a UIView, I would like my drop list in Interface Builder to list my custom colors by name. Does anyone know of a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, you can create and edit a palette in IB and then share it with your team  This article has all the details: http://natashatherobot.com/xcode-color-palette/

Edit:
That link has expired. You can see the web archive here: https://web.archive.org/web/20210303015055/http://natashatherobot.com/xcode-color-palette/

But, using named colors in the asset catalog is a better way to go now.

Comment: links can expire, can you provide more details for the solution.

Comment: But may it also support Dark Mode? Like May I choose 2 colors?? One for Dark Mode and One for Light Mode??

Comment: each "color" in asset catalog (as of 2022, not sure since when) is actually two colors — "any appearance" and "dark" ... and you can split that into "any", "light", and "dark"  or reduce it to just "any" ... crazy configurable. :)

Answer (score 100):

## Xcode 9

You now have another option to add Color Sets or Named Colors to your assets. This is new in Xcode 9.

### 1. Adding Named Colors to Your Project

[image: Adding Named Colors]

In *.xcassets > right-click > New Color Set

### 2. Assigning Name Colors to Views

[image]

Your new Named Colors show up in your Color Picker now in their own section.

Comment: But changing color afterwards does not reflect in Storyboard.

Comment: That is correct @ChintanShah. I filed an Apple Bug Report for this. I have to close Xcode and re-open it to see the storyboard update to the new color. Running the app always shows the correct color.

Comment: Must be a caching issue.

Comment: If you use this approach you can get the color in code, this way: ```myView.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "MyColor")```. Only works in iOS 11 or newer

Comment: Unfortunately, can't use this while we still have to support iOS 10!

Comment: But What If we have our own custom type?? Other than Dark and Light Mode?? Can we Extend that too in IB??

Answer (score 38):

## Custom Color Palette

In the Interface Builder's color dialog, choose the third tab. Click the gear and **New** to make a new custom color palette. You can name it whatever you want. Then click the plus (+) button to add a new color and name it. Use the color picker tool to set the color.

[image]

## Colors from RGB or Hex

Choose the second tab in the color dialog and select **RGB Sliders**. This will allow you to set the colors using RGB or hex values.

[image]

## More Help

- [XCode Tip: Color Palette](https://www.natashatherobot.com/xcode-color-palette/)
- [How to define colors in XCodes' Interface Builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889491/how-to-define-colors-in-xcodes-interface-builder)
- [How do I enter RGB values into Interface Builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565008/how-do-i-enter-rgb-values-into-interface-builder)

Comment: The first solution in this answer will create a .clr file in "~/Library/Colors" which you can add to your project Supporting Files folder and share with your team ;)