# Set custom color in Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder, background-color, user-defined

So I have this class MWColor with the following properties:

```
@interface MWColor : NSObject
+ (UIColor *)orange;
+ (UIColor *)green;
```

In the Interface Builder, for a given UIView,  I currently set the background color manually, as such:

[image]

However, I want this color to adhere to the colors defined in my MWColor class.

Can I do this in Interface Builder, probably something like this:

[image]

Or should I do that in code?

I would prefer to do it in IB

Thanks for your insights!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28501010/add-a-custom-color-palette-to-xcode-interface-builder

Comment: @Teja Nandamuri. Yeah, I've seen that, but my problem is just the other way around.